# Enviar XML a servicio REST certificado

Tags: php, post, rest, certificado

Esto tratando de enviar un XML dentro de la variable $texto a un servicio REST. Todo va bien excepto cuando trato de identificar el envío con el certificado digital. Los del servidor mantienen la callada por respuesta, no me indican si el servicio funciona bien, no funciona para el servicio contratado o algo.

Este es mi código:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$cabeceras =  ['Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8','Content-length: '.strlen($texto)];

$camino = getcwd();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cabeceras);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ($camino."/CERTIFICADO.p12"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pass);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $texto);

$respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
//var_dump ($respuesta);
//echo "\n La Dipiutación respondió: ".$respuesta."\n";

curl_close($ch);
```

Todo va bien hasta que descomento la línea curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ($camino."/CERTIFICADO.p12"));

Esta debería identificarme frente a la otra máquina, según la documentación oficial de PHP, pero en ese momento no hay respuesta ninguna. No se manda el correo. Antes daba un mensaje de error en la instalación del certificado, pero algo tocaron en el servidor ya no hace nada.

¿No es esta la forma de certificar un correo-e?
¿Existe alguna alternativa?
¿Me he comido algo?
¿No basta solo con subir el archivo CERTIFICADO.p12 sino que debe instalarse también en el servidor?

Muchas gracias

Comment: puede que hayan actualizadola config de php o curl para q soporte pkcs12 por eso se fue el error, probá con darle la option del tipo de certificado con `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'P12');` si eso no funciona, una posibilidad es usar openssl para convertir el certificado a .pem y en algunos casos armar un bundle con el CA+cert

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. La primera solución no ha funcionado. Paso a la segunda

Answer (score 0):

Ya me contesto yo. En este caso ha resultado imposible hacerlo con un certificado PFX, en concreto una extensión .p12. Fue necesario convertir dicho certificado a formato PEM pero en el mismo servidor porque el proceso crea un archivo con extensión .nokey.pem otro con extensión .key y otro más con .withkey.key

Si se hace fuera del propio servidor quizá no funcione, no llegué a probarlo.